# running the program doesn't print the second printf statement

Tags: c, printf

whenever I run the program the second print statement isn't printing. I tried using a function but I'm new to C and don't really understand anything. I've also attached my activity as I'm not sure how to do the other things on it.[activity photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEWKi.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 1000

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    FILE *input_file = fopen("cstest.c", "r");
    char line [LINE_LENGTH];
    
    //while loop to ger
    while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
    {   
        int ch = 0;//ch is the cast
        int lines = 0;//start with one because 
        if (input_file == NULL) 
            return 0;
    
        while (!feof(input_file))
        {
            ch = fgetc(input_file);
            if (ch == '\n')
            {
                lines++;
            }
        }//end while
    
        printf("lines: %d\n", lines);

    }//end while loop

    while (fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, input_file) != NULL)
    {   
        int ch = 0;//ch is the cast
        int lines = 0;//start with one because 
        if (input_file == NULL) 
            return 0;

        while (!feof(input_file))
        {
            int characters = 0; 
            char c;
    
            for (c = getc(input_file); c != EOF; c = getc(input_file))
                // Increment count for this character
                characters = characters + 1;
    
            printf("characters: %d\n", characters);

            fclose(input_file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only read the file once.  Only your first while loop will ever be entered (assuming no read errors).

Comment: `man rewind` if you want to read the file more than once.

Comment: Or if you need to access the contents of the file more than once, _save_ the results of reading it the first time.

Comment: Also please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You should use the return value from the file reading functions themselves to control the loops. For example `while(fgets(...) != NULL)` and `while((ch = fgetc(input_file) != EOF)`

Comment: ...missing a closing parenthesis `while((ch = fgetc(input_file)) != EOF)`